# Keycloak-Tomcat-Adapter: Is there a alternative path for 'keycloak.json'?

Tags: java, tomcat, keycloak

I try to secure my Java Servlet application with keycloak. All works fine but I don't like the fact that my 'keycloak.json' file is inside my release located. The reason is, if the keycloak definitions are inside my war, so I need for different installations different build processes or the same client credentials on different installations.

My idea was now to place the 'keycloak.json' outside my WEB-INF. Is this possible? Other ideas to solve this problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you check the [KeycloakOIDCFilter](https://github.com/ChristianLutz/keycloak/blob/1.9.x/adapters/oidc/servlet-filter/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/servlet/KeycloakOIDCFilter.java) you see there are three additional parameter.

- keycloak.config.resolver
- keycloak.config.file
- keycloak.config.path

We are using file parameter and works like charme.

Comment: Thanks for the response I will check this out.

Comment: @"Christan Lutz" How do you include the filter class? Is there a dist jar that contains the spezific class or do you copy it from GitHub to your application?

Comment: now it works, only add a context-param with name 'keycloak.config.file' to web.xml

Answer (score 3):

The Servlet-Filter mentioned above is not necessary.

It is enough to set a context-parameter, like @OkieOth said in his comment.

E.g. set a Parameter like this

```
<Parameter name="keycloak.config.file" value="MY-PATH/keycloak.json" override="false"/>
```

within your context (beside the for keycloak configured Valve) or a "context-param" in your web application deployment descriptor (/WEB-INF/web.xml):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>keycloak.config.file</param-name>
    <param-value>MY-PATH/keycloak.json</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For more Detail about context-params, see [The Context Container](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) in section "Context Parameters".